# Jest test fails when i'm using toContain with input that have (1 in it

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

Test fails when i check with .toContain('1 scenario (1');

I'm trying to check that output (string) of has string

```
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
```

the output

```
    > nx run plugins-cucumber7079355:test·
    ..
    1 scenario (1 passed)
    2 steps (2 passed)
    0m00.005s (executing steps: 0m00.000s)····
     >  NX   Successfully ran target test for project plugins-cucumber7079355··
```

with matches on `1 passed` and `2 passed`

Test code that fails

```
    const result = await runNxCommandAsync(
        `test ${testProjectName}`
    );

    const expectedOutput = `
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
`;

    expect(result.stdout).toContain(expectedOutput);
```

when im checking `1 scenario (` it passes but when i check `1 scenario (1` it also fails.

Comment: have you tried `expect.stringContaining` ?

Comment: yep, didn't work
i also tried to test via regex

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the test and found that actual output is

```
[2m> [22m[2mnx run[22m plugins-cucumber7560000:test

[32m.[39m[32m.[39m
1 scenario ([32m1 passed[39m)
2 steps ([32m2 passed[39m)
0m00.005s (executing steps: 0m00.000s)

 

 [32m>[39m [0m[7m[1m[32m NX [39m[22m[27m[0m  [32mSuccessfully ran target test for project plugins-cucumber7560000[39m
```

so probably i will transform it to another format before check

```
1 scenario (ESC[32m1 passedESC[39m)
2 steps (ESC[32m2 passedESC[39m)
```

works well